# Yup validation, helperText added to MaterialUI Input Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup

I am using a material UI  to accept file types and upload files, I am trying to integrate Yup validation with this, however Input does not allow for a helperText within its definition, it does allow for a error which will report a red underline when cancelling out of the upload,How can I add on the helperText value to my input and receive a error message?

```
<FormControl className={classes.margin}>
                      <Input
                        className={classes.fileUpload}
                        type="file"
                        id="file"
                        onChange={onSelectFile}
                        name="file"
                        inputProps={fileRestrict}
                        error={touched.file && Boolean(errors.file)}
                        helperText={touched.file ? errors.file : ''}
                      />
                    </FormControl>
```

The helperText above will never actually render below the input component on the UI, Is there something I should be wrapping the Input within to make this work?

```
  file: Yup.mixed('Please Select a file').when('isEdit', {
    is: false,
    then: Yup.mixed().required(
      'File is required if you are uploading a document'
    ),
  }),
```

my validationSchema which is passed in via props

Comment: `helperText={touched.file ? errors.file : 'YOUR MESSAGE HERE'}` you have empty string rendering

Answer (score 1):

From the material UI TextField documentaton - https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/

> Advanced Configuration:
> It's important to understand that the text field is a simple abstraction on top of the following components: `FormControl`, `InputLabel`, `FilledInput`, `OutlinedInput`, `Input`, `FormHelperText`

You are trying to use the `FormHelperText` component however you are using the `Input` component that does not contain the `FormHelperText` component as a child. You can either separately use a `FormHelperText` component as a sibling component or you can use a `TextField` component and configure it accordingly. Many of the same props are handed down to the `Input` component. However, any others you can pass directly using the `InputProps` property of the `TextField` (note this is case sensitive, lowercase `"i"` affects with the HTML input element and upper case `"I"` affects the Material UI `Input` component)

```
<TextField 
  className={classes.margin}
  type="file"
  error={touched.file && Boolean(errors.file)}
  helperText={touched.file ? errors.file : ''}
  onChange={onSelectFile}
  InputProps={{className: classes.fileUpload}}
  inputProps={{id: "file"}}
/>
```